# Pytest ignoring certain parameters with multiple parametrize

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pytest

Im wondering if there's any way of skipping parameter pairs in the example below:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("bar", [4, 5, 6])
```

When ran like this, there'll be a total of 9 runs (1,4; 1,5; 1,6;, 2,4; 2,5; 2;6, 3,4; 3,5; 3,6). What I'm trying to accomplish is running 1 and 2 from `foo` with every parameter from `bar` and ignoring 4 from `bar` when running 3 from `foo` so that the pair of parameters 3,4 is ignored, ideally if it doesn't appear in the test output at all.

Is there any way to accomplish that in pytest? I know I could use something like:

```
if foo == 3 and bar == 4:
    pytest.skip("Something")
```

But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way since this could get messy when I'd like to ignore several parameter pairs

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```py
import pytest
from itertools import product


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "foo, bar",
    [x for x in product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) if x not in {(3, 4)}]
)
def test_something_2(foo, bar):
    assert True
```

You won't see a test for `(3,4)` in the output at all:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.8, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.4.0 -- /home/larsks/tmp/python/.venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/larsks/tmp/python
collecting ... collected 8 items

test_foo.py::test_something_2[1-4] PASSED                                [ 12%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[1-5] PASSED                                [ 25%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[1-6] PASSED                                [ 37%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[2-4] PASSED                                [ 50%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[2-5] PASSED                                [ 62%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[2-6] PASSED                                [ 75%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[3-5] PASSED                                [ 87%]
test_foo.py::test_something_2[3-6] PASSED                                [100%]

============================== 8 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

You can of course move the list of skipped pairs into a variable, which would probably cleaner if the list grows beyond a single item:

```py
import pytest
from itertools import product

ignored_pairs = {(3, 4)}


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "foo, bar",
    [x for x in product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) if x not in ignored_pairs]
)
def test_something_2(foo, bar):
    assert True
```

Comment: That does look like a solution but only partly - the example I used in my question is greatly simplified. The "real" thing has 4 parametrize fixture , some using predefined lists in different modules, some defined in the fixture itself. Using list comprehension in such a scenario sounds a bit too complicated and "messy"